# std::sort with custom comparator

Tags: c++, sorting

In the following code, why do all three `IntComparator()`, `IntComparator2` and `IntComparator3` work as the 3rd parameter of the `sort()` function? Wouldn't they have different l-value function types? Based on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort it says

> The signature of the comparison function should be equivalent to the
>   following:
>
> bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);

which seems to match `IntComparator2` better?

Also which one would be preferable? Third option seems much simpler and more intuitive.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

struct IntComparator
{
  bool operator()(const int &a, const int &b) const
  {
    return a < b;
  }
};

bool IntComparator2 (const int &a, const int &b)
{
    return a < b;
}

bool IntComparator3 (int a, int b)
{
    return a < b;
}

int main()
{
    int items[] = { 4, 3, 1, 2 };
    std::sort(items, items+4, IntComparator());

    for (int n=0; n<4; n++) {
        std::cout << items[n] << ", ";
    }

    std::cout << "\n";

    int items2[] = { 4, 3, 1, 2 };
    std::sort(items2, items2+4, IntComparator2);

    for (int n=0; n<4; n++) {
        std::cout << items2[n] << ", ";
    }

    std::cout << "\n";

    int items3[] = { 4, 3, 1, 2 };
    std::sort(items3, items3+4, IntComparator3);

    for (int n=0; n<4; n++) {
        std::cout << items3[n] << ", ";
    }

    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was just reading the reference given above; the formulation _should be equivalent to_ is indeed somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: @Codor The standard says "It is assumed that `comp` will not apply any non-constant function through the dereferenced iterator." You might be able to use `bool IntComparator3 (int &a, int &b)`, but it is undefined behaviour if `a` or `b` are modified by it

Comment: @Caleth We banned that one recently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::sort` accepts a `functor`. This is any object that can be called (with the correct parameters). The function achieves this by using templates, like the following

```
template<typename Iter, typename Comp>
void sort(Iter begin, Iter end, Comp compare) { ... }
```

`IntComparator1`, 2, and 3 are all valid functors for this comparator, since they can all be called using operator() with 2 integers.

Also like you said, the third option is indeed usually more intuitive.

Comment: Lambdas are another option, which may be more intuitive.

Comment: Right, forgot about those for a moment :D Lambdas are indeed even better usually.

Comment: As long as they're kept short and are relatively self-explanatory (and assuming they aren't useful elsewhere in your code)

Comment: The first (functor), and a lamba, also achieve a significant benefit of having a very high probability of being inlined *within* the `std::sort` algorithm implementation, something  the other two, both effectively pointers to functions, are not likely to achieve. It can make an *enormous* difference in performance. For that reason alone a functor or lambda should be high on one's priority list.

Comment: Technically functions aren't objects, but they decay to pointer-to-functions, which are.

Answer (score 2):

The `sort()` function will just call the comparator function you provided when a comparison is needed. The way your comparator gets its parameters (value, reference, const ref) is not the concern of `sort()`, it will call it the same way (passing two arguments of the same type) no matter how your comparator gets its parameters internally.
It is imperceptible from outside the comparator definition since the way we call you three functions is exactly the same.

The only thing that is requested is that the comparator takes only two arguments and they must be of the same type of the elements to be sorted.

But, passing by const ref is better because your comparator guarantees to not modify the paramaters it compares, and also that it avoids useless copies (performance gain). That is why they have written ***should be equivalent*** (which is different of ***must be equivalent***).

Comment: you miss one detail, the comparater is not allowed to modify the parameters, otherwise `sort` cannot do what one would expect. That does not imply that the parameters cannot be passed as non-const reference but if they are, then the comparater **must not** modify them

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Yes of course ! You are completely right. But if the user gives a comparator that modifies the parameters, then it is completely the fault of the user, `sort()` is not responsible for such a mistake.

Comment: I was refering to "The only thing that is requested is that the comparator..." and I dont completely agree, it is the responibility of `sort` to state what the preconditions are, and the comparater not modifying its parameters is one

Answer (score 2):

They are equivalent because the C++ specification says they both match the requirements of a binary predicate. The following extracts seem relevant.

[[function.objects]](http://eel.is/c++draft/function.objects)

> 20.14.1 A function object type is an object type that can be the type of the postfix-expression in a function call ([expr.call], [over.match.call]).224 A function object is an object of a function object type. **In the places where one would expect to pass a pointer to a function to an algorithmic template, the interface is specified to accept a function object. This not only makes algorithmic templates work with pointers to functions, but also enables them to work with arbitrary function objects.**

[[alg.sorting]](http://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms#alg.sorting)

> 25.7.2 **Compare is a function object type ([function.objects]) that meets the requirements for a template parameter named BinaryPredicate ([algorithms.requirements])**. The return value of the function call operation applied to an object of type Compare, when contextually converted to bool ([conv]), yields true if the first argument of the call is less than the second, and false otherwise. Compare comp is used throughout for algorithms assuming an ordering relation.

[[algorithms.requirements]](http://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms.requirements#8)

> 25.2.8 When not otherwise constrained, the BinaryPredicate parameter is used whenever an algorithm expects a function object that when applied to the result of dereferencing two corresponding iterators or to dereferencing an iterator and type T when T is part of the signature returns a value testable as true. In other words, if an algorithm takes BinaryPredicate binary_­pred as its argument and first1 and first2 as its iterator arguments with respective value types T1 and T2, it should work correctly in the construct binary_­pred(*first1, *first2) contextually converted to bool ([conv]). Unless otherwise specified, BinaryPredicate always takes the first iterator's value_­type as its first argument, that is, in those cases when T value is part of the signature, it should work correctly in the construct binary_­pred(*first1, value) contextually converted to bool ([conv]). binary_­pred shall not apply any non-constant function through the dereferenced iterators. **Given a glvalue u of type (possibly const) T1 that designates the same object as *first1, and a glvalue v of type (possibly const) T2 that designates the same object as *first2, binary_­pred(u, *first2), binary_­pred(*first1, v), and binary_­pred(u, v) shall each be a valid expression that is equal to binary_­pred(*first1, *first2)**, and binary_­pred(u, value) shall be a valid expression that is equal to binary_­pred(*first1, value).

As to the question on which is preferable, I'd say that is opinion based, unless in your specific case profiling shows one to be better.